# apply fullrange option on multiple loess smooth lines when subsetting the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

How could I draw different smooth lines on my plot for data included in separate time periods, but draw them both on the full range of the plot?

In my working example below, even when setting the `fullrange` argument to `TRUE`, the smooth lines limit themselves, and I get the missing values warnings (which does make sense as we are setting a new data range locally in each one of the `geom_smooth()` functions).

```r
# convert time series to data.frame, conserving date info
sb <- data.frame(Seatbelts, date = time(Seatbelts))
# convert from ts to date
library(lubridate)
sb$date <- as_date(date_decimal(as.numeric(sb$date)))
# store seatbelt law date
law <- ymd(19830131)
# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sb) + aes(x = date, y = front) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = law, colour = "red") +
  geom_smooth(data = sb[sb$date < law,],
              fullrange = TRUE) +
  geom_smooth(data = sb[sb$date > law,],
              fullrange = TRUE)
```

[image: current result: smooth lines don't span the whole range]

Warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_smooth). 
2: Removed 71 rows containing missing values (geom_smooth).
```

(currently using ggplot2 3.1.0 and R 3.5.2)

**Edit**: 
As I thought the issue was the preliminary subsetting of the data, I also tried this cleaner version, to no avail:

```r
# add before/after
sb$relative <- ifelse(sb$date < law, "before", "after")
# plot v.2
ggplot(sb) + aes(x = date, y = front) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = law, colour = "red") +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = relative),
              fullrange = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for the behaviour you're seeing has to do with the way the LOESS fit is performed; by default

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1960-01-01"), law, by = "1 day")
head(setNames(predict(
    loess(front ~ as.numeric(date), data = sb[sb$date < law, ]),
    data.frame(date = as.numeric(dates))), dates))
1960-01-01 1960-01-02 1960-01-03 1960-01-04 1960-01-05 1960-01-06
        NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

the behaviour of which is explained in `?predict.loess` (bold-face mine)

> When the fit was made using ‘surface = "interpolate"’ (the
>        default), ‘predict.loess’ will not extrapolate - so **points outside**
>        **an axis-aligned hypercube enclosing the original data will have**
>        **missing (‘NA’) predictions** and standard errors.

In order to extrapolate to points outside of the range of points used for the LOESS model we can use `control = loess.control(surface = "direct")` inside `loess`.

Unfortunately this means that we need to manually perform the two LOESS fits, predict values for two ranges of interest, and plot everything.

Here is what I would do:

1. Define a convenience function `extrapolate.loess` that predicts values for `dates` with a lower/upper confidence interval (based on an `alpha` level)

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   library(broom)
   extrapolate.loess <- function(data, dates, alpha = 0.95) {
       loess(
           front ~ as.numeric(date), data = data,
           control = loess.control(surface = "direct")) %>%
           augment(newdata = data.frame(date = as.numeric(dates))) %>%
           transmute(
               date = dates,
               front = .fitted,
               front.l = front - qnorm((1 - alpha) / 2) * .se.fit,
               front.h = front + qnorm((1 - alpha) / 2) * .se.fit)
   }
   ```
2. We now store LOESS estimates with CI's for the two ranges in a `data.frame`

   ```
   dates.left <- seq(as.Date("1960-01-01"), law, by = "1 day")
   df.left <- extrapolate.loess(sb[sb$date < law, ], dates.left)

   dates.right <- seq(law, as.Date("1990-01-01"), by = "1 day")
   df.right <- extrapolate.loess(sb[sb$date > law, ], dates.right)
   ```
3. Now we can plot

   ```
   ggplot(sb) + aes(x = date, y = front) +
       geom_line() +
       geom_vline(xintercept = law, colour = "red") +
       geom_line(data = df.left, colour = "blue", size = 1) +
       geom_ribbon(data = df.left, aes(x = date, ymin = front.l, ymax = front.h), alpha = 0.2) +
       geom_line(data = df.right, colour = "blue", size = 1) +
       geom_ribbon(data = df.right, aes(x = date, ymin = front.l, ymax = front.h), alpha = 0.2) +
       coord_cartesian(ylim = c(400, 1300))
   ```

[image]

I will not/cannot comment on how useful/meaningful these LOESS extrapolations are.

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly detailed answer, @maurits-evers ! I think you probably _can_ comment on the extrapolations and say they are rubbish.
If anyone is wondering, all the other suggested methods in the `geom_smooth()` documentation ("lm", "glm", "rlm" and "gam") will handle the `fullrange` option.

Comment: You're very welcome @stragu; I agree with you in that the `fullrange` option for `method = "loess"` is somewhat misleading. Perhaps the default for `predict.loess` changed from `surface = "direct"` to `surface = "interpolate"` at some point, but this is just a wild guess. Anyway, if this answers your question please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for others to identify relevant questions. Cheers.